# Language independent storage class?

Tags: c#, java, json, storage

so I feel like this is a thing that I've seen before, but I can't think what it's called.

I have a java program which loads up an object from a file (I'm going to call this object the catalogue).  Defining the file format, and writing the parser for it has taken a fair amount of time.  Recently I've had developers that are want to load the file so they can use the catalogue for their own tools, but are working in a different language (current just C#, but potentially others in future).

Most of our tools run out on a server, so to prevent other people having to write their own parser for the file format, I plan on having a web service running which uses my program to load the catalogue, then returns it's contents as a json string.  (Encoding the original file as json is not an option).  In future I may just return bits of the json string, since the whole contents of the file can be pretty massive.

What I'm wondering is, do I have to write my catalogue object in each language, and write a json parser for it in that language, or is there a tool that will allow me to do something similar?  I'm hoping for something that just has a simple format for declaring storage classes, generate corresponding code for various languages, and have a default serialize/deserialize for something like json.  Currently I'd need it to support java and C#.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I don't think there's a language without a Json library either built-in or by a third party.

Comment: It's not so much about parsing the json, more, if possible, I don't want to have to write/update the storage class, and the code to populate it from the parsed json in each language.  You can imagine once this gets to more than one language to support, there are going to be potential bugs that some implementations contains variables/code to populate those, and some that don't, which wouldn't show up until run time.  This risk could be minimized if I had a tool to automatically generate the code for the storage class, and for populating it, Id only have to say what members the storage class has

Answer (score 0):

As long as the target language can make a web call, and parse JSON strings, you should be OK. This covers just about all mainstream languages I think. C# is certainly OK.

Comment: It's not so much about parsing the json, more, if possible, I don't want to have to write/update the storage class, and the code to populate it from the parsed json in each language.  You can imagine once this gets to more than one language to support, there are going to be potential bugs that some implementations contains variables/code to populate those, and some that don't, which wouldn't show up until run time.  This risk could be minimized if I had a tool to automatically generate the code for the storage class, and for populating it, Id only have to say what members the storage class has